# Nonnegativity of integral, integral operator

Tags: integration, operator-theory, integral-inequality

Let $f$ be a quadratically integrable function. Does the inequality

$$ \int_0^1\int_0^1 \min(s,t) f(s) f(t) \,\mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{d}t \ge 0 $$

hold true? This is obviously related to [Mercer's condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercer%27s_theorem#Mercer.27s_condition). I thought about writing

$$2\int_0^1\int_0^t sf(s)f(t)\,\mathrm{d}s\,\mathrm{d}t=2\int_0^1f(t)\big(\int_0^t sf(s)\,\mathrm{d}s\big)\,\mathrm{d}t.$$

Does partial integration then lead to some conclusion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint. Assume that $f\in C([0,1])$ and let $F(x)=\int_0^xf(t)dt$ then, by integrating repeatedly by parts, the given integral can be written as
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1 \min(s,t) f(s) f(t) ds dt&=2\int_0^1 f(s)\left(\int_0^s tf(t) dt\right) ds\\
&=2\int_0^1 f(s)\left(sF(s)-\int_0^s F(t)dt\right)\\
&=2\int_0^1 sF(s)f(s)ds -2\int_0^1 \left(f(s)\int_0^s F(t)dt\right)ds\\
&=F^2(1)-\int_0^1 F^2(s)ds -2\int_0^1 F(t) (F(1)-F(t))dt\\
&=F^2(1)-2F(1)\int_0^1 F(t)dt+\int_0^1 F^2(s)ds\\
&=\int_0^1\left(F(1)-F(t)\right)^2dt\geq  0.
\end{align}$$

Comment: great, thanks. stupidly, i just edited your edit. i hope everything is fine now.

Comment: @Quodly It's perfect!